# How to handle click event in IE8 using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, event-handling

I have some html code

```
<div class="filters-widget bordered">
<span class="checkbox" style="background-position: 0px 0px; "></span><input type="checkbox" id="sidecity-control-name-2" name="sidecity" class="styled" value="Brisbane">
<label for="sidecity-control-name-2">Brisbane (109)</label>
</div>
```

And I have this js code

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        registerClick();
        function formSubmit() {
            this.document.getElementById("filters-form").submit();
        }
        function registerClick() {
            $('.filters-widget.bordered input[type="checkbox"]').bind("click", function () {
            formSubmit();
        });
            $('.filters-widget.bordered span[class="checkbox"]').live("click", function () {
                formSubmit();
            });
            $('.filters-widget.bordered label').bind("mousedown", function () {
                var id = $(this).prop("for");
                var span = document.getElementById(id).previousSibling;
                Custom.pushed.call(span);
            });
        };
    });
```

I use jQuery 1.6.1.
In IE8 this part of code don't work

```
$('.filters-widget.bordered input[type="checkbox"]').bind("click", function () {
                formSubmit();
            });
```

The function is not called.
How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: $(".filers etc").off("click").on("click", function() {});  Are you sure that you have the correct selectors?

Comment: why do you want to do a submit on a check box change event?

Comment: When the checkbox is set to the form is sent(update filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A check box does not have a click event. This has nothing todo with jQuery.

Instead of `click`you can use `change`:

```
$('.filters-widget.bordered input[type="checkbox"]').bind("change", function () {
    formSubmit();
});
```

See the jQuery reference:
http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: in other browsers this function is called.

Comment: @ntziolis i agree, that should work and it is the change event, not the click even. Once again, i have not read the question properly.

Comment: @Victor jQuery guarantees that the `change` event called in all supported browsers, some browsers might also raise the `click` event, but this is NOT guaranteed, so simply use the `change` event then you an be sure it works

Comment: even when the `display: none;` for the input checkbox?

Comment: how is somebody supposed to click/change it if it is hidden?

Comment: Checkbox hidden, Instead, it is span element

Comment: Well that's a different problem then, for the `span` you need to use the click event since it does not support `changed`.

Comment: How best to handle the event or the checkbox label (can get a "checkbox id")?

Comment: in general when a label is clicked the `focus` event of the labeled element is raised, so in your case the `focus` event of the checkbox, so bind a handler to the `focus` event of the checkbox rather than binding anything on the label